# How do I make different Buttons show up in Custom Title Bar in Android

Tags: android, customization, titlebar

I have seen many guides on how to dynamically change the text of the custom title bars based on what activity is opened but I don't know how to add or put in different buttons for different activities.

For example in one page I want to add a '+' button to add more friends but I don't want that there for the other activities. Thanks

Comment: Do you want + button in titlebar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is better way is to create the custom title bar for each activity that you want to change, this code to change the title bar add below the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
 final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkin);
    if (customTitleSupported) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.title);
    }
  final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    if (myTitleText != null) {
        myTitleText.setText(R.string.title_check_in);
    }
```

where R.layout.checkin is the activity layout and R.layout.title is the title layout
Thank you.

Comment: If i use setContentView (R.layout.checkin) as my custom title layout, how do i show the rest of the activity?

Comment: sorry for miss understading,but now i have edited the answer, if you have any other problem the tell me i can put the title bar xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how did you make it so that your custom title isn't the size of the regular title.

Comment: that all u need to define in title layout better is set the root tag height wrap content.